# How do you run javascript with only a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am working on a web site project which requires that the web page display tooltips on hover. For reasons I won't go into here, I decided to use a library from a site called [dyn-web.com](http://www.dyn-web.com/code/tooltips/documentation.php).  The [library](http://www.dyn-web.com/code/tooltips/documentation.php) works great but I need to make one small change to the way it works, which will make it a perfect fit for my application.  Trouble is, I can't figure out how it works!

Everything I've read says that you can't execute javascript code from within CSS.  But that seems to be exactly what this library does.  To create a tooltip for any element (anchor, div, span, etc), all this library requires you to do is:

1. Include a <script src= > tag to the library file
2. Add two class names to the HTML element that will host the tooltip, one called "showTip" and the other is a key into a JSON object containing the tooltip text
3. Add the tooltip text to the JSON object mentioned above
4. Create a style to format the tooltip how you want it to look

If you'll notice, nowhere in these steps is mention of any event handlers. Moreover, there's no class (that I can find) called *showTip*. There's no JQuery or other dependencies. So how does the javascript get executed?

I don't want to jump in and start changing the library willy-nilly without knowing how it works, and I've been pulling out my hair trying to figure it out.  Can one of you smarter-than-me folks explain it?

Comment: I don't see any CSS files or code included in your steps, only a script file. Whatever is in the file included by the `<script src="...">` tag runs as a script. That script does stuff, and some of the stuff it does is dependent on the presence of a `class` attribute.

Comment: In short, it's not executing JavaScript within CSS; it's executing CSS within JavaScript which is certainly possible. Longer explanation as an answer coming up!

Comment: _"So how does the javascript get executed?"_ The last line in the script adds an event handler for the `load` event which starts the "setup" process: `dw_Event.add( window, 'load', dw_Tooltip.init );`

Comment: Ah, so many good answers!  I had not considered that the javascript ran first - I'm accustomed to script tags like that just loading functions to be executed later.  Also, I didn't mention that I'm working in Meteor, which actually doesn't require that I even put the script tag in - the code is automatically picked up by virtue of it's location in the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the steps you listed, it seems as if [Dynamic Web Coding](http://www.dyn-web.com/code/tooltips/documentation.php) library uses the JavaScript to apply CSS attributes into elements. You can not run JavaScript inside CSS, but you can certainly apply CSS using JavaScript!

What the library probably does is look at all of the elements with class `showTip` with JavaScript using `document.getElementsByClassName("showTip")`. Then, it looks at the other class on that element and assumes that as the key to the tooltip with the tooltip text.

Then, it probably creates an element for the tooltip using `document.createElement()` and then injects that into the document using `document.appendChild()` or `document.insertBefore()`. They can probably add some class to the tooltip so your CSS rules are applied using the `.className` property.

It also likely used `document.addEventListener()` to listen for when the user hovers over and leaves the element. You don't need to add this code because the `<script>` tag you added has called `document.addEventListener()` for you.

All of these things require something known as the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM) which is something JavaScript coders use to manipulate the HTML document. This is actually really powerful and cool, so you can check out a good tutorial on it [at TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dom/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.  I knew it would be something obvious that I was overlooking - it just didn't occur to me that some of the javascript was being executed when it was loaded, instead of just being a collection of functions for later use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run JavaScript from a "CSS Class".

The example you give runs JavaScript by including a `<script>` element.

I'm not going to reverse engineer it because it is not formatted in a way that is particularly human readable. That said, searching the file finds `showTip` so it presumably searches the DOM for that **HTML** class (maybe with `querySelectorAll` since it certainly uses that method for *something*) and binds event handlers with JavaScript (probably with `addEventLister` since it contains a call to that method).

> If you'll notice, nowhere in these steps is mention of any event handlers.

The JS file uses `addEventListener`

> Moreover, there's no class (that I can find) called showTip.

You said you added it to an HTML element in a previous step. As mentioned above, the string appears in the JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

It works with event delegation, it listens to events on the entire body and ignores events on elements without the magic class names (`showTip`).

Excerpt from http://www.dyn-web.com/code/tooltips/js/dw_tooltip_c.js:

```
   initHandlers: function() {
        var _this = dw_Tooltip;
        if (_this.ready) {
            return;
        }
        if (!_this.forTouch) {
            if (_this.activateOnClick) {
                dw_Event.add(document, 'click', _this.checkForActuator, true);
                dw_Event.add(document, "mouseup", _this.checkDocClick, true);
            } else {
                dw_Event.add(document, 'mouseover', _this.checkForActuator, true);
            }
            dw_Event.add(document, "keydown", _this.checkEscKey, true);
            if (!_this.activateOnClick && _this.activateOnFocus) {
                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    dw_Event.add(document, 'focus', _this.checkForActuator, true);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    dw_Event.add(document, 'focusin', _this.checkForActuator);
                }
            }
        } else {
            dw_Event.add(document, 'mouseover', _this.checkForActuator, true);
        }
        _this.ready = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one way by which you can make custom tool-tip(s). This is little out of box & requires only HTML and CSS to perform the magic.
"Use JS to add more interactivity".

```
<html>
   <style>
       h1 { position: relative; }

       h1:hover:after {
          content: attr(data‐hover‐response);
          color: black;
          position: absolute;
          left: 250px;
          top: -40px;
          border: solid 2px gray;
          background-color: red;
       }
   </style>
   <body>
      <br><br>
      <h1 data‐hover‐response="I am tooltip !"> I will show tooltip on Hover! </h1>
   <body>
</html>
```

CodePen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdPQxP

Comment: Thanks, that's good to keep in my mental toolbox, but my tooltips have to also work on touchscreens (part of the reason I chose this library).